# MySQL client not working in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, mysql

I have installed MySQL via Windows installer from the [MySQL Site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)

When I click on MySQL client, it shows me nothing. It just closes very fast, which is why I can't see anything.

I have 4 parts:

```
MySQL connector c6.0.2
MySQL connector Net 6.4.4
MySQL installer
MySQL Server 5.5
```

When I try to access in MySQL server 5.5, I can't.

Comment: Have you tried starting the service?

Comment: No how can I do it?

Comment: just go to services and then look for mysql, right click and start

Comment: I saw the status is started no need to start should i restart?

Comment: I restarted nothing changed

Comment: do you know how can I access it from command line? maybe it will work

Comment: I'm now uninstalling the whole and installing again! maybe it will work

Comment: Connecting from command line: `mysql -u USERNAME -h SERVER_HOSTNAME -p`

Comment: I tried this one now I can work with mysql! I went to c:\programfiles\Mysql server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe :) but client is not up i dunno why! however I can make queries:)

Comment: Can you please **answer your question** if you were able to solve it? Or is it not really working yet? Please reply with `@slhck`.

Answer (score 1):

@slhck
sorry I didn't check here recently.
I used MySQL via command line and my problem solved.I can create dbs and work with it via command line but clicking on it has problem still.
this was my idea which i done it and now work easily.

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db) which I was a newbie working on command line this is the path which should be entered in commandline I had problem because no need was for going to mysql.exe too.
going to bash is enough then sign as root or another user.

```
c:\programfiles\Mysql server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe
```